# How to display Jupyterlab output in new tab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am trying to get an output tab in Jupyterlab that shows the output of my code. Right now I can right-click on a cell output in the notebook and create an output view -- but this view does not update as I execute additional cells. Is there a way to do this (a setting or extension)?

I envision something like the Python extension in VS Code that allows you to split the screen and run cell code on the left and see the output on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click the tab which shows the name of the file you are editing.
In the popup window select **New View for Notebook.**
A new tab (in a new window) will be opened and the output(s) of your file will be shown there.
Here after, if you give additional codes and run them, you will see that the output is updated in the **New view.**
Particularly, when you have a cell with `markdown` format, your input in that cell   will be rendered (as you type) in the **new view** as a formatted one!

Comment: Is it possible to turn that view into a proper browser tab?

Comment: @Bananach did you solve this? It would be awesome to have one browser tab per display so I'm really looking for this.

Comment: @marc-cejalvo no, and all the power jupyterlab users I've talked to didn't have na answer either

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I can right-click on a cell output in the notebook and create an output view

That's right.

[image]

> but this view does not update as I execute additional cells.

That's right too. It is THE view of THE output for the cell you selected. If you produce some new output on THAT cell, it will update. Each cell has its own output area.

> Is there a way to do this (a setting or extension)?

I'd suggest you explore the "output" widget. I can be very versatile once you learn to use it well (easier said than done).

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html

> but this view does not update as I execute additional cells. Is there a way to do this (a setting or extension)?

Yes.
https://github.com/xiaohk/stickyland
This extension allows (among other things) to have one/multiple cells to rerun every time you run **any** cell.
The 2+1 guys there made a brilliant extension that works flawlessly. I can't praise them enough.

> I envision something like the Python extension in VS Code that allows you to split the screen and run cell code on the left and see the output on the right.

That is also available.

[image]

It is under View > Render side by side

[image]

You are mixing up too many things.

See this:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2897