# how to print something in a new window in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ide, window, jupyter

I have seen that in some IDEs, when you print something , a new window opens up.

my question is that is it possible to have the same thing for jupyter notebook ?

P.s:
It would be better if it was customizable; like being able to change the background color of the new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want the newer generation of Jupyter interface, JupyterLab. (At least if you want this soon. I don't know what will be possible as Jupyter notebook 7 starts using more of the underlying machinery that JupyterLab uses.)

#### Default JupyterLab

Using default current JupyterLab, **you can make a separate window for any output that you can drag around and arrange how you want**. Right-click on an output cell and select from the menu '`Create New View for Output`'. That will open a new window that respects the current JupyterLab theme. (There's a lot of theme adapting abilities so maybe that can provide what you need as far as background.) Once the new window is generated you can click and drag it around the JupyterLab window to arrange it relative to the notebook and then release when you have it outlined the way you want.  You can try it right in your browser by clicking [this link](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/ece14f28f9b751a11646270eb839) and letting the session spin up.
(This ability was covered in [an answer to a similar question 'How to display Jupyterlab output in new tab?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67240261/8508004).)

Similarly, you can have a window that keeps updating with the most recent output by using an attached console and toggling on '`Show All Kernel Activity`'. When you have a notebook open, either right-click and select '`New Console for Notebook`' or go under the main 'File' menu and select '`New Console for Notebook`'. This will open a console and you can then right-click on the console pane and toggle on '`Show All Kernel Activity`'. As you run things in the notebook, the output will show at the bottom of this window as well. Even rich output like plots and dataframe displays. You can click on the tab and drag to arrange this window as you wish in the main JupyterLAb pane. See some example images using this [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/console-would-not-automatically-run-code-typed-in-notebook-kernel/12512/3?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-have-new-printouts-at-top-of-cell/12683/2?u=fomightez).

Related:
It's not a separate window; however, a nice feature of JupyterLab is switching to 'View' to 'Render Side-by-Side' where the output goes to the side of the code cell and not below. Alternatively, you can modify the output cell in some ways like you could do in the classic notebook interface, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69575883/8508004).

#### Sidecar extension of JupyterLab

There's [an extension called sidecar for Jupyterlab](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar) that I believe has more options. I wonder if you could combine widgets to control the background as you seek. Don't know about the layering possibilities there.

#### ipylab extension of JupyterLab

[ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab#ipylab) has even more abilities than sidecar for customization, with 'SplitPanel' and 'DockPanel'. Scroll through [the examples shown](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab#examples) to get an idea of the possibilities. There's also a '`launch binder`' badge so you can try it out.
(You may also want to see [Related projects](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab#related-projects) listed at the bottom of ipylab's github page.)